# String inside switch case returns null

Tags: java, methods

All variables are correctly initialized, and are only defined inside this one method, calls day as an integer, then sets to a string to be able to be read and then split into characters to create the word format.
Also, mathematics with dayL, an integer, sometimes returns the StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception, which i understand to be due to an error due to the inequality i create with the .length();
Thank you for any help.

```
    public static void bday()
{
    s_day = Integer.toString(day);
    dayL = s_day.length();

    switch (dayL)
    {
    case 1:
        if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1)
        {
            word_day = "first";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2)
        {
            word_day = "second";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 3)
        {
            word_day = "third";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 4)
        {
            word_day = "fourth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 5)
        {
            word_day = "fifth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 6)
        {
            word_day = "sixth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 7)
        {
            word_day = "seventh";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 8)
        {
            word_day = "eighth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 9)
        {
            word_day = "ninth";
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        //teens

        if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 0)
        {
            word_day = "tenth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 1)
        {
            word_day = "eleventh";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 2)
        {
            word_day = "twelfth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 3)
        {
            word_day = "thirteenth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 4)
        {
            word_day = "fourteenth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 5)
        {
            word_day = "fifteenth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 6)
        {
            word_day = "sixteenth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 7)
        {
            word_day = "seventeenth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 8)
        {
            word_day = "eighteenth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 1 && s_day.charAt(1) == 9)
        {
            word_day = "ninteenth";
        }

        //twenties

        if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 0)
        {
            word_day = "twentieth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 1)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-first";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 2)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-second";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 3)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-third";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 4)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-fourth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 5)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-fifth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 6)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-sixth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 7)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-seventh";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 8)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-eighth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 2 && s_day.charAt(1) == 9)
        {
            word_day = "twenty-ninth";
        }

        //thirties

        if(s_day.charAt(0) == 3 && s_day.charAt(1) == 0)
        {
            word_day = "thirtieth";
        }
        else if(s_day.charAt(0) == 3 && s_day.charAt(1) == 1)
        {
            word_day = "thirty-first";
        }
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Your birthday is: " + s_month + " "+ word_day);
}
```

Comment: `1 != '1'` and `2 != '2'`, etc. Why not `switch (day)`? What is the point of the rest of your code?

Comment: this was for a horoscope generator project, i over complicated and chose to go the long way by using strings, using int-string-string conversion instead of string-string or so i think, thank you for the suggestion btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you compare a character, you do it wrong.

```
s_day.charAt(0) == 1
```

should be

```
s_day.charAt(0) == '1'
```

But even that is way more complicated than it needs to be. You have the day as an `int` in the variable `day`, right? So why not just make an `if` statement based on that:

```
if (day == 1) {
  word_day = "first";
}else if (day == 2)
//and so on
```

Comment: i cant believe i overlooked the quotes, thank you for the suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

`s_day.charAt(0)=='1'`

And I recommend that you can write thie method like this:

```
String [] days={"first","second","third",.......,"thirty-first"};
word_day=days[day%31];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refactor this code like @fei_hsueh proposed or like below:

```
Map<Integer, String> days = new HashMap<>();
days.put(1, "first");
days.put(2, "second");
days.put(3, "third");
...

private static String bday(int day) {
    return days.get(day);
}
```